# Question on domain restriction of a quadratic

Tags: quadratics, inverse

Why do we restrict the domain of a quadratic function, from $[0,\infty)$ rather than $(-\infty,0]$ if we want to find an inverse? Is this just an arbitrary thing, or is there a reason why this is easier for learners to understand?

Comment: It's a convention. It's the same as why we say $\sqrt{4}=2$ and not $-2.$ We need a definite inverse and long ago it was the non negative solution which was chosen.

Comment: $$x^2+x+c\ne (-x)^2+(-x)+c$$